# React Native - Require Image source with default source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am fetching a list of IDs from an API, most of which I have an associated image stored locally. However, some IDs don't have an image and thus return an error when trying to require their source.

Here is how I'm getting my source:

```
<Image style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} source={require('../assets/character-images/' + this.character.id + '.jpg'))}/>
```

How can I have a default fallback source? I wouldn't even mind just not loading the image if it is not found... I just can't get rid of this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the onError event on the image, and render a different image instead. A sample component that accepts a default image can be found bellow.

```
export default class ImageWithFailback extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hasError: false
    };
  }
  _onError = () => {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }
  render() {
    const failBackImage = <Image source={this.props.default} style={this.props.style} />;

    if (this.state.hasError) return failBackImage;

    return (
      <Image
        {...this.props}
        onError={this._onError}
        renderIndicator={_ => failBackImage}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since assets you are loading are predefined in project why not simply check if you are able to load it?

Say for example you have `character-images/1`, `character-images/2`, `character-images/3` then you could do something like this:

```
const availableCharacterIds = ['1', '2', '3']
const assetToLoad = availableCharacterIds.includes(`${this.character.id}`) ? 
  require('../assets/character-images/' + this.character.id + '.jpg') : null
```

Then in your render JSX:

```
<Image style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} source={assetToLoad}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good but my concern is the fact that I'd have to track a list of available IDs when I'm trying to do this dynamically. Is there any way to check if the image source exists and adding it to this "availableCharacterIds" dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this small function to see if the image exists, then dynamically decide to render it or not:

```
const tryRequire = (path) => {
  try {
   return require(`${path}`);
  } catch (err) {
   return null;
  }
};
```

then in your render method

```
{this.state.ids &&
    this.state.ids.map((id) => {
        return (
            <Image style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} source={this.tryRequire('../assets/character-images/' + id + '.jpg') !== null ? require('../assets/character-images/' + id + '.jpg') : require('../assets/fallbackimg.png')}/>;
        );
    })}
```

or if you dont want to render an img at all (no fallback img), you can simply add a filter

```
{this.state.ids &&
    this.state.ids
        .filter((id) => return this.tryRequire('../assets/character-images/' + id + '.jpg') === null)
        .map((id) => {
            return (
                <Image style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} source={this.tryRequire('../assets/character-images/' + id + '.jpg')}/>;
    );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically check if the file is present or not you can use [fs.exist](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#existspathstringpromise) and then add it to an array of available ids if its present and then while rendering you can check if id you are about to render is available or not and if its not available show the default image.

You can use code like below to check if fileExists.

```
checkIfFileExists=(id)=>{
RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(PATH_OF_FILE).then((exist) => {
    return exist;
})
.catch(() => return false)
}
```